# Getting pubsubhubbub hub working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, websub

I have followed the instructions found at http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/DeveloperGettingStartedGuide to setup a hub.
When I start the hub I get following warnings

```
$ sudo python2.5 google_appengine/dev_appserver.py pubsubhubbub/hub/
INFO     2010-03-04 12:29:57,928 appengine_rpc.py:157] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2010-03-04 12:29:57,959 appcfg.py:329] Checking for updates to the SDK.
WARNING  2010-03-04 12:29:58,272 datastore_file_stub.py:418] Could not read datastore data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore
WARNING  2010-03-04 12:29:58,273 datastore_file_stub.py:418] Could not read datastore data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore.history
INFO     2010-03-04 12:29:58,349 dev_appserver_main.py:465] Running application pubsubhubbub on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
```

http://pastie.org/853356

When I point my browser to `http://localhost:8080` I get a nasty exceptions.AttributeError thrown in my browser & console

```
ERROR    2010-03-04 12:31:27,735 dev_appserver.py:3000] Exception encountered handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2969, in _HandleRequest
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 406, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2238, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2156, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2052, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/pubsubhubbub/hub/main.py", line 116, in <module>
    import dos
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1158, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1806, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1158, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1708, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1158, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1659, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/home/pentarim/webdev/pshb/pubsubhubbub/hub/dos.py", line 219, in <module>
    offset_multi=memcache.offset_multi,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'offset_multi'
INFO     2010-03-04 12:31:27,749 dev_appserver.py:3029] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

http://pastie.org/853357

As a python newbie would need help, any ideas?

Comment: Does anybody know current and working instructions on how to setup a hub?

Comment: The code.google link redirects to git hub as on Oct 16. Any other links with hub setup? Has Push been replaced by something  better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial at http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/DeveloperGettingStartedGuide is outdated, you need to use **at least google app engine 1.2.8** to make it work (where New memcache offset_multi method and batch support in incr and decr. is added)

Comment: Can't believe there isn't a real tutorial that actually works out there though. Trying to set up a hub in Python, and no tutorial that works!